# Node Application Spawning Multiple Child Processes & Consuming All CPU Cores

Tags: node.js, mongodb, child-process, spawn

### Problem

I am running a NodeJs application which is doing frequent insert operations in MongoDb & the problem is, it is spawning multiple child processes even if I am trying to run it in fork mode.

Initially, I suspected PM2 is causing the problem but then I tried following ways to start the application but I can still see multiple child processes being spawned -

- PM2 is fork mode
- PM2 it cluster mode with 1 instance
- VSCode Debugger
- Terminal Command ( `node app.js` )

### Stats

I managed to collect various stats to prove that (`I have updated the machine specific information` )-

- Node App is spawning multiple processes
- These processes are consuming all of the CPU cores

---

**Process Status**

command - `ps -aefL | grep "29475"`

`machine+  8750 28307  8750  0    1 12:10 pts/24   00:00:00 grep --color=auto 29475`

`machine+ 29475 18579 29475  0   10 10:58 ?        00:00:05 node /app/api.js`

`machine+ 29475 18579 29476  0   10 10:58 ?        00:00:00 node /app/api.js`

`machine+ 29475 18579 29477  0   10 10:58 ?        00:00:00 node /app/api.js`

`machine+ 29475 18579 29478  0   10 10:58 ?        00:00:00 node /app/api.js`

`machine+ 29475 18579 29479  0   10 10:58 ?        00:00:00 node /app/api.js`

`machine+ 29475 18579 29481  0   10 10:58 ?        00:00:00 node /app/api.js`

`machine+ 29475 18579 29501  0   10 10:58 ?        00:00:00 node /app/api.js`

`machine+ 29475 18579 29502  0   10 10:58 ?        00:00:00 node /app/api.js`

`machine+ 29475 18579 29503  0   10 10:58 ?        00:00:00 node /app/api.js`

`machine+ 29475 18579 29504  0   10 10:58 ?        00:00:00 node /app/api.js`

---

**Virtual Memory Statistics**

Command - `vmstat 2 100`

`procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----`

`r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st`
`11  0      0 603060 818492 3718660    0    0    16    40   73   59  7 28 65  1  0`
`6  0      0 601664 818492 3718696    0    0     0   130 3383 6112 76 24  0  0  0`
`6  0      0 611208 818492 3711916    0    0     0    22 3472 6378 77 23  0  0  0`
`7  0      0 610932 818492 3711920    0    0     0    16 3932 6441 77 24  0  0  0`
`5  0      0 617304 818492 3711980    0    0     0   100 3480 6151 72 25  2  1  0`
`6  0      0 612584 818496 3718788    0    0     0   102 3634 7433 67 25  6  1  0`
`8  0      0 612128 818496 3718788    0    0     0    18 3318 5584 77 23  0  0  0`
`8  0      0 617552 818496 3713300    0    0     0     0 3468 6787 78 22  0  0  0`
`7  0      0 618096 818496 3712132    0    0     0    38 3743 6913 76 23  0  0  0`
`12  0      0 618040 818496 3712528    0    0     0   146 3852 7434 76 24  0  0  0`

---

**System Resource Usage Status**

Command - `top -p 5733 -p 29475` (mongod & node app processes)

`top - 12:30:06 up 1 day,  3:21,  1 user,  load average: 8.91, 4.81, 3.31`

`Tasks:   2 total,   0 running,   2 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie`

`%Cpu(s): 72.1 us, 27.7 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st`

`KiB Mem : 16336020 total,   686496 free, 12203100 used,  3446424 buff/cache`

`KiB Swap: 16686076 total, 16686076 free,        0 used.  2746100 avail Mem`

`PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND`
`5733 root      20   0 1296480 366432  29724 S 204.0  2.2  63:07.65 mongod`
`29475 machine+  20   0 1351412 118900  30960 S   8.8  0.7   0:10.82 node /app/api.js`

---

**System Monitor**

[image]

---

### Findings

If I stop the running node service -

- CPU usage goes down
- The child processes disappear

---

**Why is the node application spawning so many processes?**

**Why the count of child processes always comes out to be 10?**

Let me know if further information is required.

Comment: I think all are not the process they are threads. as nodejs single process run 4 `worker-threads`. And also you have enable clustering that will spawn `4 process`. Trace process with `pstree` command you will get clear picture, which is process and which is worker thread and also disable clustering to monitor. You will get clear picture about that.

Comment: Well I tried without clustering as well but ended up getting the same result. It would be interesting to see the response of `pstree` command though. I will get back to you after trying it. Thanks!